# Faking raw strings in VS2012?

Tags: c++, regex, string, visual-studio-2012

Is there any convenient way to fake raw strings in VS2012? (I'm thinking using a preprocessor macro, but am open to suggestions.)

My use case is a fairly long, but static, list of regular expressions, that are nearly unreadable with all of the escaped `\`'s.

The alternative to having code that looks like this:

```
p[TokenType::Comment       ] = "(/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*+/)|(//.*)";
p[TokenType::Float         ] = "[0-9]+\\.[0-9^(A-Za-z)]*";
p[TokenType::Integer       ] = "[0-9]+";
p[TokenType::String        ] = "\\\"([^\\\"\\\\\\\\]|\\\\\\\\.)*\\\"";
p[TokenType::Identifier    ] = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*";
p[TokenType::Operator      ] = "\\^|\\*|\\/|\\+|\\-|\\=";
p[TokenType::BinaryOperator] = "(\\=\\=)|(\\+\\=)|(\\-\\=)|(\\*\\=)|(\\/\\=)";
p[TokenType::WhiteSpace    ] = "\\s+";

p[TokenType::EndOfStatement] = ";";
p[TokenType::ListStart     ] = "\\(";
p[TokenType::ListDelimiter ] = "\\,";
p[TokenType::ListEnd       ] = "\\)";
p[TokenType::BlockStart    ] = "\\{";
p[TokenType::BlockEnd      ] = "\\}";
```

(which is just plain ugly, and difficult to maintain.)

I've found is to put everything in a text file and load it at runtime, but I'd rather not have to distribute that. Suggestions?

Comment: Write a tool that takes a text file and spits out a .cpp file with string literals properly escaped, perhaps?

Comment: You could at least split up the regexes into smaller pieces and concatenate them. Each piece is reusable and much easier to look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a code generator that takes the input file in a simple format and outputs the escaped `.cpp`, then add it to your pre-build steps.

In Python, assuming an input file like this:

```
Comment=(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)|(//.*)
Float=[0-9]+\.[0-9^(A-Za-z)]*
```

the whole thing would boil down to something like:

```
def c_escape(s):
    result = ''
    for c in s:
        if not (32 <= ord(c) < 127) or c in ('\\', '"'):
            result += '\\%03o' % ord(c)
        else:
            result += c
    return result

import sys
inFile = open(sys.args[1])
outFile = open(sys.args[2], 'w')
for l in inFile:
    idx = l.find('=')
    k,v = l[0:idx], c_escape(l[idx+1:])
    outFile.write('p[TokenType::%s]="%s";\n' % (k, v)
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer is: put strings into resources, then load them at run time.

Comment: I explicitly stated that I didn't want to distribute a text file containing the patterns in question.

Comment: Resources sre disrtibuted inside of executable module, so you don't need to distribute separate text file. Visual Studio contain resource editor and compiler as standard and you don't need to install any third-side tool or utility like Python, nor writing and maintaining scripts for it.

Comment: That's somewhat platform-specific. I need this to build in VS2012, but not *exclusively* in VS2012. (Also XCode / clang). There are workarounds for that, but a generic solution like a code generator feels a lot more portable. (I did not state that it needed to be cross-platform, so +1)